# adding link to SummaryLink field using Powershell not working

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, spfield

I have created a Summary Link field and added it to a page layout and created a page based on this page layout. I have tried to add links to the summary link using powershell but the links do not appear. here is my code:

```
$web = get-spweb "http://siteurl"
$pubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($web)
$pagesListName = $pubWeb.PagesListName
$defaultAspxFile = $pubWeb.GetPublishingPage("$pagesListName/default.aspx")
$summaryLinkFieldValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.SummaryLinkFieldValue

$groupLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SummaryLink("My group")
$groupLink.IsGroupHeader = $true 
$summaryLinkFieldValue.SummaryLinks.Add($groupLink)

$linkLink =  New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SummaryLink("my link")
$linkLink.LinkUrl = "http://www.test.se"
$summaryLinkFieldValue.SummaryLinks.Add($linkLink)

#$defaultAspxFile.CheckOut()
$pageItem = $defaultAspxFile.ListItem

$pageItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId]::SummaryLinks] = $summaryLinkFieldValue
$defaultAspxFile.Update()
$web.Update()
```

when I check $pageItem[[Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.FieldId]::SummaryLinks] in powershell it contians the link but it does not appear on the page.

Comment: You are not updating the pageItem, call pageItem.Update()

Comment: no it didn't help, I added it

Answer (score 1):

You must publish and approve the page:

```
$page = $defaultAspxFile.ListItem.File
$page.Publish("")
$page.Approve("")
```

Comment: It didn't solve the problem either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what did it for me to add it to a Summary Links Webpart

```
$newLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.SummaryLink("New Summary Link")
$newLink.LinkUrl = "https://yourfarm.com/site/web"

$fieldValue = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Fields.SummaryLinkFieldValue($currentWP.SummaryLinkStore)
$fieldValue.SummaryLinks.Add($newLink)
$currentWP.SummaryLinkStore = $fieldValue.ToString()

$wpm.SaveChanges($currentWP)
```

Adapted from the C# code found here 
 - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/76023737-0295-4820-8c94-f54f1c71918a/add-a-link-and-a-group-to-a-summarylinkwebpart?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy